# new CO2 leak at regulator connection

Tags: carbonation, kegging

I had to exchange my first CO2 tank and when I went to connect the regulator to the new tank I am able to screw it on but there is still a leak from the connection not matter the tightness. Is this something that I can fix or is this a problem with the tank?

Comment: Did you replace the nylon washer that sits inside the connector from the regulator to the tank?

Comment: Is the O-ring intact? They are finicky so I've actually gone to something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Regulator-Washers-Centering-Fittings/dp/B07Q5VLSD5/ref=pd_lpo_1?pd_rd_i=B07Q5VLSD5&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

Check for a gasket on the connection to the CO2 tank. The symptom you are describing is very common and usually caused by the absence of a small plastic washer-like ring that sits inside the threaded connector.

My CO2 supplier even provides tanks with a spare gasket attached to the valve, in case the original falls out.

If you are not missing a gasket, a good test is to connect everything and submerge it in water. Bubbles will form and rise where the CO2 is leaking, and you can address the problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a new tank, unless you suspect a problem with the regulator.